# Copy from one column to another , entire column to specific text

Tags: excel, replace, ms-office, vba

I know this is bit difficult but i wonder if any one can help.
I want to copy one entire column data in to other column but When we copy the data , it should only replace one specific word in that column , Not entire content.

For example

```
Column A    
1234        
5252         
3265         
999        

Column B

This is **

This is **

This is **

This is **
```

I want to replace Column A data to Column B data but it should only replace ** , So whatever is in the column A will be replaced by ** in Column B , but it should not alter any other text in Column B

I wonder if anyone can solve this? Any macro in excel? it is just a find and replace macro but more complicated

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing. It would be helpful if you would change or reformat the example to make clearer 1) what is in column A, 2) what is in column B, and 3) what you want the final text string to look like.

Comment: Thanks for that , I am trying to make it clear but it does not allow me enter a picture , I have uploaded the picture of the column here http://lapraj.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/blog-post.html

Comment: i just need to copy entire colmn data fro one column A to Column B but in Column B i only need to change some specific text and Not entire column, If you check the pic , you can understand

Answer (score 2):

Though this could certainly be done in VBA, why not just use a SUBSTITUTE formula? You could then do a Copy/Paste Special to turn the formulas into values. For example, the formula in cell C2 would be `=SUBSTITUTE(B2,"****",A2)`.

[image]

Comment: + 1 I agree for the Non VBA approach to this.

Comment: Thanks dear , you have solved this in such a simple way , i have just tried it and it works like charm , thank you